# Gradle error after upgrading to Android Studio to 2.0 Preview and using Instant Run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex

When I try to run my project which works great on Android Studio 1.5 I get the following error:

```
Error:Access to the dex task is now impossible, starting with 1.4.0
1.4.0 introduces a new Transform API allowing manipulation of the .class files.
See more information: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api
```

I saw some questions here regarding this error, but all answer are to downgrade Gradle to 1.3 version, which I can't do with the new Android Studio and the Instant Run option.

Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Android Studio 2.0 or 1.5 ? Which version of gradle and gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Android studio 2.0, with gradle 2.8 and gradle build tools of 2.0 alpha.

Comment: I think that you have to change some in your tasks. There is a issue open in the bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191782&q=label%3AReportedBy-Developer&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by enlarging the max heap size in my build.gradle
add this to your android closure:

```
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
 }
```

not sure what it has to do with the new api